# Action Script Movable Points And Lines

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, instance, movieclip

I'm pretty new to Action Script and I have a couple of questions of a game i am making:

1. How can i make a MovieClip object drag able by the mouse?
2. If i have two MovieClip instances, is it possible to make a new shape/MovieClip objects in that looks like a line and which will connect then?
3. I have functions checking if the 'nodes' movie clip instances collide with the 'line' movie clip instances, now these all are different functions and conditional, but is it possible to check if ALL of them are true?

Thanks for ANY help. Seriously, ANY help is great.

Answer (score 0):

Well first making a MovieClip draggable is pretty simple, you just need to do mc.startDrag(); and mc.stopDrag(); to stop the movment...

Usually this is done along with the MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP events example:

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
});

mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
});
```

You can also define to lock center or a rect which limits the drag on the startDrag method, basically if lock center is true the mouse will stick to the center of the MovieClip while dragging and the rectangle will limit the drag area for example a canvas.

Second question,

You can create a new MC in AS3 like this var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
then draw the line in the MC with the graphics...

A more detailed example:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
mc.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x000000);

//start drawing the line
mc.graphics.moveTo(10,10);
mc.graphics.lineTo(10,100);
mc.graphics.endFill();

//Position your new movie clip
mc.x = 80;
mc.y = 60;
addChild(mc);
```

Finally im not sure how you implemented the collision detection but you may be able to have an array of states for each item and change them when something has collided then you can loop into the array to check for all of them to be true...

Comment: mc.graphics.moveTo(10,10);
mc.graphics.lineTo(10,100); // how can i make it so that instead of numbers i will have the position of two movie clip objects (AUTOMATICALLY)?

Comment: You can take the reference from the other movie clips, last say you want it from the center... 

mc_container.graphics.moveTo(mc1.x + mc1.width / 2, mc1.y + mc1.height / 2)
mc_container.graphics.lineTo(mc2.x + mc2.width / 2,  mc2.y + mc2.height / 2)

Comment: Also this wont do it automatically... you can either redraw when you drop the movie clip or create an ENTER_FRAME listener when you start the drag and on that listener redraw, just remove the listener on the stop drag...

Answer (score 0):

1) look at the [`startDrag/stopDrag`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29) methods. Then can be called on Sprite or any of its subclass

2) yes, you can use the [`graphics`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) object of any Sprite to draw arbitrary lines/shapes

3) for collision detecting multiple objects, you'll have to step through each object. try using a `for` loop

Comment: yeah I do know how to use the graphics object, the question i was meaning to ask was how to make it go from one point to the other (like how to calculate the position, angel, size etc...)

Comment: and thnx for the quick answer